# What is the best approach to measure a similarity between texts in multiple languages in python?

Tags: python, nlp, multilingual, similarity, word-embedding

So, I have a task where I need to measure the similarity between two texts. These texts are short descriptions of products from a grocery store. They always include a name of a product (for example, milk), and they may include a producer and/or size, and maybe some other characteristics of a product.

I have a whole set of such texts, and then, when a new one arrives, I need to determine whether there are similar products in my database and measure how similar they are (on a scale from 0 to 100%).

The thing is: the texts may be in two different languages: Ukrainian and Russian. Also, if there is a foreign brand (like, `Coca Cola`), it will be written in English.

My initial idea on solving this task was to get multilingual word embeddings (where similar words in different languages are located nearby) and find the distance between those texts. However, I am not sure how efficient this will be, and if it is ok, what to start with.

Because each text I have is just a set of product characteristics, some word embeddings based on a context may not work (I'm not sure in this statement, it is just my assumption).

So far, I have tried to get familiar with the [MUSE](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE) framework, but I encountered an [issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/1755) with `faiss` installation.

Hence, my questions are:

- Is my idea with word embeddings worth trying?
- Is there maybe a better approach?
- If the idea with word embeddings is okay, which ones should I use?

*Note:* I have Windows 10 (in case some libraries don't work on Windows), and I need the library to work with Ukrainian and Russian languages.

Thanks in advance for any help! Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your task is about a fine-grained entity recognition. I think you have a well defined entities: brand, size etc...
So, these features that defines a product each could be a vector, which means your products could be represented with a matrix.
You can potentially represent each feature with an embedding.
Or mixture of the embedding and one-hot vectors.

Here is how.

0. Define a list of product features:
   product name, brand name, size, weight.
1. For each product feature, you need a text recognition model:
   E.g. with brand recognition you find what part of the text is its brand name.
2. Use machine translation if it is possible to make unified language representation for all sub texts. E.g. `Coca Cola` to
   `ru Кока-Кола, en Coca Cola`.
3. Use contextual embeddings (i.e. huggingface multilingial BERT or something better) to convert prompted text into one vector.
4. In order to compare two products, compare their feature vectors: what is the average similarity between two feature array. You can also decide what is the weight on each feature.
5. Try other vectorization methods. Perhaps you dont want to mix brand knockoffs: "Coca Cola" is similar to "Cool Cola". So, maybe embeddings aren't good for brand names and size and weight but good enough for product names. If you want an exact match, you need a hash function for their text. On their multi-lingual prompt-engineered text.
6. You can also extend each feature vectors, with concatenations of several embeddings or one hot vector of their source language and things like that.

There is no definitive answer here, you need to experiment and test to see what is the best solution. You cam create a test set and make benchmarks for your solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no predefined sets of brands, sizes, etc. There might also be products without any characteristics at all (for example, `lemons`). And new products appear pretty often (and there are a lot of them), so creating a list of existing characteristics is probably not an option

Comment: You don't need a pre-defined list of brands or product types in this solution. However, you need to decide what is the best way to represent product characteristics in a list of features. You need to have a solution to extract a value for each feature and a way to compare them with each other. If you have no clue maybe you can start from a subset of product ontology for the semantic web: https://schema.org/Product

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely give it a try!

Comment: Found this approach useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Milvus](https://milvus.io/) that adopted `Faiss` to search similar vectors. It's easy to be installed with docker in windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

Word embedding is meaningful inside the language but can't be transferrable to other languages. An observation for this statement is: if two words co-occur with a lot inside sentences, their embeddings can be near each other. Hence, as there is no one-to-one mapping between two general languages, you cannot compare word embeddings.

However, if two languages are similar enough to one-to-one mapping words, you may count on your idea.

In sum, without translation, your idea is not applicable to two general languages anymore.

Comment: But don't there exist already pre-trained word embeddings for multiple languages? Where embeddings are aligned in a common space. In the MUSE/FastText (https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/aligned-vectors.html), for example?

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi I'm afraid so! Your task without using translation tasks cannot be done solely by word-embedding.

Comment: Ok, got it! Maybe there is another approach?

Comment: I don't think @OmG is understanding OP's point. I would agree and say its possible with pertained word embeddings for multilanguage

Comment: @AriK great, thank you! Which ones would you recommend to begin with?

Comment: MUSE looks good! Start there @OlegIvanytskyi

Comment: @AriK So, please explain how?

Comment: @OmG there is literarily an entire GitHub repository that OP linked that does it

Comment: @AriK Yes, but they are using a dictionary! A translator!

Comment: It's probably likely that the words he uses are in that dictionary.. lol @OmG

Comment: @AriK Yes, Indeed!

Comment: @AriK Unfortunately, I have encountered troubles while trying to start working with MUSE (https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/1755). Any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: responded to your issue with some links to potential solutions to people with same problem

Answer (score 1):

Does the data contain lots of numerical information (e.g. nutritional facts)? If yes, this could be used to compare the products to some extent. My advice is to think of it not as a linguistic problem, but pattern matching as these texts have been assumably produced using semi-automatic methods using translation memories. Therefore similar texts across languages may have similar form and if so this should be used for comparison.

Multilingual text comparison is not a trivial task and I don't think there are any reasonably good out-of-box solutions for that. Yes, multilingual embeddings exist, but they have to be fine-tuned to work on specific downstream tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is not a lot of numerical information (only size and even size is not always present).

Comment: I didn't quite understand this part: `these texts have been assumably produced using semi-automatic methods using translation memories.` These are just names taken from the websites of grocery stores. So, there might be even the same products presented by different texts in one language (for example, there might be just 'Milk' and 'Milk 18oz' - both texts written in Ukrainian), and I need to measure how similar are these texts

Comment: OK, I thought you had more detailed information on the products. One approach would be use machine translation to translate all the texts to some common language (e.g. English) and then use term/document vectors to identify similar texts. Check out this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch I have found this feature extremely useful in similar cases.

The most difficult part of your problem is the multilingual aspect as it is quite difficult to make multiple languages share the vector space in embedding models.

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thank you!